# Label equation not working with document class report

Tags: latex, texmaker

Hi I am using the class report ( my University wants me to use it ) , but I cannot label any equation . An except of my code :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {Home/} }
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cool}
\usepackage{esdiff}
\begin{document}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:1}
x(t+\Delta) = x(to) + \int_{to}^{to+\Delta} f(x,t) dt 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this means that no label appears on the equation..

Comment: Ciao Andrea! `\begin{document}` seems to be duplicate in your code, otherwise it compiles sweetly and the label shows!

Answer (score 0):

What are you calling label? 
With your code, the equation will be correctly numbered with (1) at the end.

If you want to call it later in the code, add for example

```
considering Eq.~(\ref{eq:1}) blablabla
```

Comment: the problem is that actually the equation is NOT numbered with (1) at the end and I don't understand why ...
I am using this version of texmaker :
Texmaker 4.4.1

Comment: Did you add the phrase after? Sometines if the report class is given by your university the package autonum is load.

Comment: there is no package autonum in my code . I added your phrase but still not appearing anything.

Comment: "the problem is that actually the equation is NOT numbered with (1) at the end and I don't understand why": Try to compile your (almost) minimal example after commenting unnecessary packages...it all should work @AndreaAngeletti